# What does α - β equal if a quadratic equation has roots of α and β

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, quadratics

> Considering the following equation $$px^2 - qx - r = 0$$ whose roots are $\alpha$ and $β$. What would $α - β$ be in terms of $p$, $q$, and $r$?

I understand that I have to use the sum and product of roots, and have found both in terms of $p$, $q$, and $r$:

$$α + β = \frac{q}{p}$$
$$αβ = -\frac{r}{p}$$

I do not know how I would use this to find $α - β$ though, any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: $$(\alpha-\beta)^2 = (\alpha+\beta)^2-4\alpha \beta.$$

Comment: I should get α − β = ± sqrt[ (q^2 + 4rp) / (p^2) ] right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. You should get $\alpha-\beta = \pm \sqrt{\frac{q^2+4rp}{p^2}}$.

Comment: Thank you, just to double check the most simplified version would be $\alpha-\beta = \pm\frac{\sqrt{q^2+4rp}}{p}$ correct?

Comment: @grahamcracker1234 Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

your assumption $\alpha - \beta = \frac{q}{p}$ is wrong.
$$
\alpha + \beta = \frac{q}{p}
$$ is correct one
then you can use the formula $(\alpha - \beta)^2=(\alpha + \beta)^2-4\alpha \beta$ and you can solve for $\alpha - \beta$.

Comment: my fault I incorrectly typed something I've updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

$$(\alpha-\beta)^2 = (\alpha+\beta)^2-4\alpha \beta = \dfrac{4pr +q^2}{p^2} $$
$$ \alpha -\beta =\pm \dfrac{\sqrt{ 4pr +q^2}}{{p}}$$
Actually you can write out the qudratic roots separately and subtract one from the other.. even if it appears brute force. The discriminant  is an important part of the result. (It vanishes for equal roots).